# How to do transaction with JSON API on Neo4j?

Tags: json, http, transactions, neo4j

I decided to use *neo4j*. Because it's almost the only proven, graph DB with full ACID transaction. But I couldn't find how to do transaction with HTTP/JSON API. How can I do transaction over HTTP/JSON API?

PS.
I don't need RESTful thing. It's enough only with HTTP/JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the API batch operation.  It allows you to do multiple operations in as single API call, and all the operations are wrapped in a transaction that succeed or fail as one. Documentation here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-batch-ops.html